# Deploying ARM templates using powershell: asking for subscriptionID even when it is defined

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-rm-template

I'm trying to deploy a service on Azure using ARM templates and "deploy.ps1" script previously downloaded from Azure (using portal).
There is the section in the "deploy.ps1" file where you can specify subscription ID, resource group, etc:

```
param(
  [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
  [string]
  $subscriptionId = "ID",

  [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
  [string]
  $resourceGroupName = "Name"

   ......

  $templateFilePath = "template.json",
  [string]
  $parametersFilePath = "parameters.json"
  )
```

Even though SubscriptionID is defined, when I'm executing the "deploy.ps1" script, system keeps asking for subscription ID:

```
cmdlet deploy.ps1 at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
subscriptionId:
```

Could you please help me to solve this issue?

Comment: PowerShell does not support default values for mandatory arguments.

Comment: In other words, either remove the `Mandatory` attribute or make sure you always supply a value when you call the function.

Comment: @Tomalak, thank you very much for the explanation. It runs now. There is another problem arose, but it is beyond the scope of this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in this case the error was due to the fact that powershell script had some of the parameters defined as `Mandatory` and you cannot assign default values to mandatory parameters (as @Tomalak hinted).

Comment: Just add the subscription in the parameter file and it should prompt you for it.